# See what services were restarted during apt installation

Tags: apt, dpkg, services

When installing packages with dpkg, I'm getting the following warning:

[image: restart services]

I don't mind restarting the services, but I would like to know what services were restarted. Is there a way of knowing?

```
# cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
```

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Select "no" and it will ask you everytime before restarting service

Comment: Thank you so much! Solved!

Comment: @AkshajSingla  write it as an answer; and you can get rep/upvotes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is to select "No". Then it will ask you every time before restarting any service.